# Install software from Windows PE

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, sccm, wim

I have a base wim image file that I apply by booting into window pe and installing on a devices hard drive.

After the base image is applied I would like to install custom software depending on what is needed, similar to a task sequences done by sccm imaging.

What tool or command line would let me accomplish this?

Comment: The proper procedure to accomplish what you want would involve installing the software, and creating a windows installation image, that includes the software you want installed.  What you want is not possible.  You will be unable to install software to your Windows installation from within WinPE.  What you can do is install the software to your Windows installation, create a new windows image from that installation, and then apply the new image (which already includes the software you want installed).

Comment: I guess my sub question is how is Microsoft able to accomplish this.

Comment: What do you mean?  Microsoft simply creates a Windows Installation Image (WIM).  SCCM would be the tool to use to install software, to images already deployed on machines, but you already know that.

Comment: @ramhound I think he wants to know the underlying technology through which sccm or mdt allow to install software during OSD after the image is applied

Comment: @Syberdoor - The author asked specifically WinPE  The author should edit and clarify their question.

Comment: Yeah the question should definitely be rephrased

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not install Software from within WinPE to the full OS but rather reboots, let's Windows do it's configuration and then hooks itself into the now running real OS and continues the isntallation from there. The method used afaik is the setupcomplete.cmd file. This is basically an normally empty file that is always executed at the end of a windows setup (see detailed documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-a-custom-script-to-windows-setup)). I think nothing stops you from using the same file. You can hook a script (maybe more powerful than cmd) in there and install whatever you want (probably needs to be silent, user interaction in that phase does not really work that well).

Another method to get software to run during a Windows setup would be modifying the unattend.xml. [Several passes allow for a RunAsynchronousCommand step](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-deployment-runsynchronous-runsynchronouscommand) that will execude code where you could again hook yourself in. I always found the answer file modifications a little tedious especially if you have to debug so I would recommend the cmd file.